# How do I make a branch at an old commit which I have already made changes to?

Tags: git

Here's what I'm doing. My master branch has a bug in it and I have identified an old commit using `git bisect` which is the latest commit which does not exhibit the bug.

I have had this commit checked out and made a few fixes to eliminate compiler warnings, so I'd like for these changes (unrelated to the original bug) to eventually get included.

What I want to do at this point is make a new branch here, which will have this old commit (the last non-bugged commit) as parent.

I suspect the answer is to just commit here, using `-b branchname`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `commit -b`. You should `git checkout -b branchname`, then `git commit` as usual. This will leave you with a new branch with one new commit on it, with the commit you previously checked out as its parent.

Comment: Okay. Looks like checking out the branch doesn't mean it will try to overwrite the changes I made. Good.

Comment: Unless you give it specific pathnames to overwrite, `git checkout` will never overwrite modified files, but instead abort harmlessly. `git checkout -b` doesn't touch the working tree at all since it is creating a new branch with the *same* tip commit.

Comment: What if I wanted to merge the current changes with a particular commit? What's the command for that?

Comment: @StevenLu If the particular commit has no children, check it out and then use `git commit --amend`. If it has children and has not been published, then commit the changes and use `git rebase --interactive` to make the new commit a `fixup` of the old commit. If it has children and has been published, then you shouldn't alter it.